# Unable to replace the error image using javascript

Tags: javascript, php, image, youtube-api

Hi am unable to replace the error image in php variable and javascript

```
 $youtube_ext='https://i.ytimg.com/vi/'.$youtube_id.'/hqdefault.jpg';
 $youtube_original='https://i.ytimg.com/vi/'.$youtube_id.'/maxresdefault.jpg';
```

where youtube id is the videoid in youtube

```
 <img src='<?php echo $youtube_original;?>' 
   onError="this.onerror=null;this.src='<?php echo $youtube_ext;?>';" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use

```
this.setAttribute('src', <?php echo $youtube_ext;?>)
```

instead of :

```
this.src='<?php echo $youtube_ext;?>';
```

Have a good day !